# Problem with proof of multivariable limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I've got a problem with this limit:
${\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{ x^{5} + 2y^{3} }{ x^{4} + y^{2} }}$
Can you help me, please? I think it equals 0, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split into two parts. Look first at $\frac{x^5}{x^4+y^2}$. At any point other than the origin, it has absolute value $\le |x|$. Then look at $\frac{2y^3}{x^4+y^2}$.  If you like, but it is not necessary, we can say that $\left|\frac{x^5+2y^3}{x^4+y^2}\right|\le |x|+2|y|$ if $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks :) I haven't thought of it.

Comment: You are welcome. You were right about the limit.

Answer (score 0):

$$
{\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{ x^{5} + 2y^{3} }{ x^{4} + y^{2} }}=
{\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{ \frac{\partial x^{5}}{\partial x} + 2\frac{\partial y^{3}}{\partial y} }{ \frac{\partial x^{4}}{\partial x}  + \frac{\partial y^{2}}{\partial y}  }}
=\dots
$$
where the equality comes by L'Hospital. Continue using L'Hospital and should be zero eventually.